# Excel VBA - Add chart with custom range source

Tags: vba, excel, charts

i have an Excel sheet looking like this:
[image: Excel-Sheet]

Now i want to write an Excel VBA code which adds a Chart of the Type: xlAreaStacked

The other Thing i want is, that i want to Group the values of the same category.
That means, i dont want a Chart which has 3 Sources, i want 2 sources. (Sorry for my bad english)

When i am using the Macro-Recorder i get following Code:

```
Range("A1:D4").Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(276, xlAreaStacked).Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Tabelle1!$A$1:$D$4")
ActiveChart.SetSourceData
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Tabelle1!$B$1:$D$1" 'X Values are set to the Years
```

And following Chart:
[image]

**Now what i want is:**
The same Chart as above, but i want to summarize the values of the Toys (same category). How can i get this Chart with Excel VBA and the Excel Sheet above?

[image]

Comment: Use a PivotTable (and then a PivotChart) or a new row or something else to sum it!